# Why does my assigning a string in R result in an integer instead?

Tags: r, variables

I'm first importing my data as CSV.

```
file1 <- read.csv("file1.csv")
file2 <- read.csv("file2.csv")
```

Then if I run:

```
> file2$heading3[10]
[1] Wantedstring
Levels: random another andanother level4 fifthlevel
```

So I'm trying to assign 'Wantedstring' to a place in file1.

```
file1$heading2[10]<-file2$heading3[10]
```

But then when I check to see if it worked, I get:

```
> file1$heading2[10]
[1] "3"
```

Why would this be? I can't figure out how to get the text to assign, instead of what looks to me to be a random number.

Comment: use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your `read.csv` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will also work to set the `as.is` argument to `TRUE`:

```
file2 <- read.csv("file2.csv", as.is=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are implicitly reading in strings as "factor" class vectors (see `? factor`). You can change this by setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your `read.csv()` call.